# Transparent conversion on Intellij property files

Tags: java, internationalization, intellij-idea

I have been using `Transparent Native to ASCII conversion` setting on my Intellij Idea IDE with no problem. When I now come back to the project, and make another change on i18n text file (messages.properties), I get notified of a huge amount of changes on the indicator, that tells which lines I have changed after recent commit to SVN.

The changes appear on the first touch on the file and the changes occur on Scandinavian letters (å, ä, ö).

The change is like this:

```
    old value = \u00f6
    new value = ö
```

I see this kind of changes on every scandic letter. On subversion history the same change is between any past version compared to the current. The funny thing is I have just been some months away from the project and when coming back the issue raises.

Meanwhile I was as a consultant on another company away my own company and they had the same kind of issue unsolved also there. They were thus editing i18n files on windows text editor, but that won't help me, 'cause I see the \u00f6 stuff also at gedit. I have not Windows editor, because this is Linux machine.

So, any idea what is going on there at Intellij idea?

Comment: asking question directly on jetbrains website is usually best solution -  usually they provide correct answers in couple of hours

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda, I track all StackOverflow questions with `intellij-idea` tag and answer within hours (usually instantly). I would not say that getting reply in the forums is faster.

Comment: well, my experience is that you also track yourtrack and answer there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your IntelliJ IDEA version, but [similar issue was fixed](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-24267) in IDEA 11.

Comment: Thanks for rapid answer CrazyCoder! I'll have to update my IDE and see if that was the issue.